# "command not found" when running a shell script. What did I break?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I'm on OSX Snow Leopard.

Here's the full contents of `grr.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo wow
```

When I try to run it from terminal:

```
$ grr.sh
-bash: grr.sh: command not found
$ /bin/sh grr.sh
wow
$ sh grr.sh
wow
$ bash grr.sh
wow
```

Okay. Fair enough. I'll give it executable permission, then try again:

```
$ chmod +x grr.sh
$ grr.sh
-bash: grr.sh: command not found
$ chmod 755 grr.sh
$ grr.sh
-bash: grr.sh: command not found
```

Hmmm. Maybe it'll work if I use bash explicitly? I'll change the file's contents to:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo wow
```

And I get the exact same results. What could I have broken?!

One last thing! In case you're curious...

```
$ which sh
/bin/sh
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Absolutely nothing. Only executables in one of the directories in `$PATH` can be run directly, and `.` is (usually) never in `$PATH`. Specify the path to the executable, i.e. `./grr.sh`.

Comment: +1.  Also of note, the current directory *is* on the path on Windows systems by default, and is highest in priority.  This crucial difference is probably the source of the asker's confusion.

Comment: You were first by 9 seconds! Thank you!

Comment: You save my macbook

Answer (score 8):

Is the location of grr.sh in the `$PATH` variable? If not, you'll need to enter:

```
./grr.sh
```

if you are in the same folder as grr.sh. If not, then provide the full path to it.

Answer (score 8):

the permissions for the file are wrong. Try the following commands:

```
  $ chmod 777 file.sh
  $ ./file.sh
```

Comment: I would never use 777 or read write execute for all (user/group/other). Could be a security hazard. Just set execute for the user you are running the script with instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, and what ./grr.sh means, is that in this directory, run the command grr.sh. The single . means in the working directory. Otherwise, your shell assumes you are trying to run a command in your $PATH.